# tsung: parsing respone of a request in dyn_variable using regex

Tags: regex, erlang, tsung

I am trying to capture the response of a HTTP request in TSUNG in a dynamic variable.

```
   <request subst='true'>
          <dyn_variable name="my_response" re=".*" />
```

I actually need to capture the line with '200 OK' response.
I tried a few other options.
       re="200 OK"   , re=".*200 OK.*"

None of the options are working.

from controller log

```
=INFO REPORT==== 25-Jan-2016::15:45:39 ===
       ts_search:(6:<0.97.0>) DynVar (RE): Match (my_response=<<>>)        
 Converted: <<>>
```

Why am I getting empty list(or binary)? Need help with the proper regex. Thanks!

Comment: @legoscia - Can you help please?

Comment: Just guessing: if your string is multiline, try `(?s).+`, or `[\s\S]+`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I tried [200 OK]+ . I need to capture if that line with '200 OK' exists or not. It did not seem to work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  - I was able to capture complete response with headers ( my response happens to be empty and I need data in headers) using  `([\s\S]*)`. Thank you for that. My issue is I need to capture '200 OK' from the header.

Comment: Good, half done! Try a capturing group like `[\s\S]*?(.*200 OK.*)`. The value must be inside `.group(1)`. However, that does not make much sense, unless the `re` uses `re.match` here.

Comment: `"([\s\S]+200 OK[\s\S]+)" `  This did the trick! . Thank you so much

Comment: Good, I added an answer with a short explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex based on a `[\s\S]` construct (=matches any character including a newline):

```
([\s\S]+200 OK[\s\S]+)
```

Apparently, the Tsung version you are using utilizes the `re.match` method and the line you need is not the first one.